# Do I need a visa to travel to Malta?

Tags: schengen, europe, eu, permits, malta

I'm an Indian national and I got a job offer in Malta. My future employer has applied for a residence permit on my behalf. About a month ago, they told me that my residence permit application has been approved and attached a letter from Identity Malta saying that my request for residence permit has been 'acceded to' and that I may proceed to Malta to take up the employment there.

The HR from my future employer thinks that I can travel to Malta now that my residence permit is approved. But I'm a little doubtful about that. From what I read online, the residence permit is a plastic card or something which I don't have with me yet and what I have is the email copy of an acceptance letter. The acceptance letter even says that I need a visa to travel in paragraph 3:

> In this regard you are requested to present this letter to the pertinent Maltese consulate or the foreign consulate representing Malta in matters regarding the issue of a visa in order that facilitation may be given to you to be issued with a visa. The latter will enable you to travel to Malta.

I'm attaching a redacted copy of the acceptance letter. Can someone please let me know if I can travel with just this document or if I need something else. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do you intend to use it to travel, for tourism -- or to move there to live and work long term?

Comment: yes but you need aply for work permit.

Answer (score 6):

> In this regard you are requested to present this letter to the pertinent Maltese consulate or the foreign consulate representing Malta in matters regarding the issue of a visa in order that facilitation may be given to you to be issued with a visa. The latter will enable you to travel to Malta.

In ordinary English, this means:

> We're asking you to take this letter to the Maltese embassy in your country so we can give you a visa that will let you travel to Malta. If there is no Maltese embassy, then we have an agreement with some other country that their embassy will issue the visa for us.

The letter isn't enough to travel: you use the letter to get a visa.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the letter, you need to go to the Consulate to get the Malta Visa.

The consulate is situated in N60, Panchsheel Park North, Panchsheel Park, New Delhi, Delhi 110017, India. The details below.

https://foreignaffairs.gov.mt/en/Embassies/Hc_New_Delhi/Pages/HC_New_Delhi.aspx

Once you have reached the Malta, you can proceed with the actions mentioned in the last part.